# How to create and use Android Library project on other projects

Tags: android, jar, project

What I want to accomplish is the following:

1. Create a custom component with it's own interface and interaction
2. Create a .jar with that custom component
3. Consume that .jar in another Android project and be able to edit some of it's values

I've done since now:

**1. Create a custom component and extract it's jar following** [this link](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2010/08/quickly-create-jar-artifact/)

The content of the custom component looks like this:

**The main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="Yes!! I'm a custom component!"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

With it's **MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

And it's own **AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.test_uc"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
<application android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

**2. Add it on my main project.**

**3. Use it in my main xml project like this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World, MyActivity"
        />
<test_uc android:layout_height="fill_parent" /> // SEE THE ITEM HERE
</LinearLayout>
```

But if I go to check the interface, I can't see the `test_uc` content, or modify anything of it.

So, my question is:

**How to build a custom component, build it as a jar file, add it on a main project and be able to use it's properties or even see it in my interface?**

Please, I'm a bit lost on this. Any idea will be really thankful!!!!

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html

Comment: What I did is more or less what explained in your link, but I still have no idea on why I can't visualize the content of my .jar file in my maincontent.xml..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing in my case, was:

1. Create an `Activity`.
2. Give that activity to the user.
3. Use it as a library.

As a .jar is only a compressed acivity, that was enought for my purpose.

I did this because in my case, I had to make some event subscriptions, and this way was easier for the user.